# Why does my webcrawler return nothing when i run it?

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import re
import os

site = "https://woodme.dk/"

r2 = requests.get(site)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
img_tags = soup2.find_all("img")

urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]


for url in urls:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$', url)
    with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
        if 'http' not in url:
            url = '{}{}'.format(site, url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        f.write(response.content)

os.mkdir("Gathered_Photos")
i = 1

for index, img_link in enumerate(urls):
    if i <= 10:
        img_data = requests.get(img_link).content
        with open("Gathered_Photos/" + str(index + 1) + '.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(img_data)
        i += 1
    else:
        f.close()
        break
```

I am trying to make a simple webcrawler to gather all the images on a website, but when i run i i get no errors, but no output either it just runs and then does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Your request got blocked by the website:

```
site = "https://woodme.dk/"
r2 = requests.get(site)
print(r2.text)
```

displays

```
<html><head><title>406 Security Incident Detected</title></head><body><h1>406 Security Incident Detected</h1><p>Your request was blocked. Please try again later (or don't).</p><hr>Xm-qYrBRS5ojKl5V1cxeKgAAABE</body></html>
```

It appears that woodme.dk put in place security rules to prevent crawling.

[More information about HTTP 406](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/406-not-acceptable)